Unity asking me to install 2D Sprite , even though it already is
I am creating my first 2D game on unity and when I click on Sprite Editor it gives me this error:(https://i.sstatic.net/7A56XVae.png)
When I do Window >> Package Manager >> 2D Sprite, this is what I see: (https://i.sstatic.net/XIzpOAPc.png)
There is no "install" button since apparently it's already been installed with the 2D package. I've tried reimporting the asset, which is just a tileset thing I've downloaded. I've tried restarting the project. Please help!! I'm stuck

@bolov OP already stated though that they searched for the mentioned package in the Package Manager and there is no option to install as it already is installed supposedly (see second image)

Try closing and reopening unity.  Or try uninstalling the package and reinstalling it.

@hijinxbassist I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Thank you for responding anyway! I've also tried downloading many different versions of Unity editors hoping that one will work, because when I try downloading the recommended ones it keeps giving the validation failed error. I'm stuck :(
